# How to read dictionary type of json return from API in Xamarin?

Tags: json, api, dictionary, xamarin, flask

So i've created a flask API and this is the return from the API:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "name": "McLaren"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Ferrari"
        },
        "5": {
            "name": "Porsche"
        }
    }
}
```

How to read it in Xamarin? or maybe can Flask API return a array of object?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the json list to a collection in C# .

Firstly,define a class with the same property of the json

```
public class MyObject
{  
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Install the package **Newtonsoft.NET** from Nuget

And then you could convert it like

```
List<MyObject> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(data);
```